# Generated Entity reports DELETE do not work

Tags: java, spring, angularjs, jhipster

I'm using JHipster 0.13 with JDK 1.7.0.55 on MacOSX Maverick. Everything works fine so far.

My Problem is that I have generated a new entity and can add new ones after some modifications. But when i click on the delete button nothing happens in the frontend. In the console in Chrome i get 

`DELETE http://0.0.0.0:9000/app/rest/products?productId=1 405 (Method Not Allowed) angular.js:8081
XHR finished loading: DELETE "http://0.0.0.0:9000/app/rest/products?productId=1".`

The backend logs the message: 

`[WARN] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'DELETE' not supported`

The delete method is already defined by the generator and as far as i understand this it should work.

Any other places i need to check/modify to get this to work ?

In AngularJS is have defined this service.js:

`myapp.factory('Product', ['$resource',
        function ($resource) {
            return $resource('app/rest/products/:id', {}, {
                'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
                'get': { method: 'GET'},
                'delete': {method: 'DELETE'}
            });
   }]);`

On the Java side i have:

`/**
    * DELETE  /rest/products/:id -> delete the "id" product.
    */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/rest/products/{id}",
            method = RequestMethod.DELETE,
            produces = "application/json")
    @Timed
    public void delete(@PathVariable Long id, HttpServletResponse response) {
        log.debug("REST request to delete Product : {}", id);
        productRepository.delete(id);
    }`

That is in the same class that have the methods to add and save, that works.

Comment: And you're sure that you have a DELETE resource that you can use?

Comment: I edited my post and added the code that is use on the server side and the client side. For me the code looks good and i do not understand why i get a Page not found for the delete call...

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake. Rename the wrong parameter in the view with a refactoring. The id was not submitted and the REST Mapping with /delete/{id} didn't matched.